# finding if a file exists in a directory in php

Tags: php, html, image

I have exhausted my brain and cant seem to a good way to structure my code, the solution I have works but i need to simplify it. Ok say I have $id = $_GET["id"]; and that $id = 352 ... now,

**Scenario**:

The code below is where user selects an image to upload:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE id = '$_GET[id]'");

<input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" />

<?php if(isset($query) && file_exists("../uploads/properties/".mysql_result($query, 0, "id").".jpg")) { ?>

<img height="100" src="../uploads/properties/<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>.jpg" />

<a target="_blank" href="delete_script/deletepic.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>">Delete image</a>

<?php } ?>

<input type="file" name="image2" id="image2" />

<?php if(isset($query) && file_exists("../uploads/properties/".mysql_result($query, 0, "id")."_2.jpg")) { ?>

<img height="100" src="../uploads/properties/<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>_2.jpg" />

<a target="_blank" href="delete_script/deletepic2.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>">Delete image</a>

<?php } ?>
```

If you take a look at the **`src`** on the `img` tag the difference between the two is one image will be uploaded as **352.jpg** and the other will get saved as **352_2.jpg**. I have 10 images that the user can upload so the images will be saved as:

1: 352.jpg

2: 352_2.jpg

3: 352_3.jpg

4: 352_4.jpg

5: 352_5.jpg

6: 352_6.jpg

7: 352_7.jpg

8: 352_8.jpg

9: 352_9.jpg

10: 352_10.jpg

Now for the tricky part:

When the link  is clicked this page `deletepic.php` will run with the following code:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$file_path = "../uploads/properties/".$id."_".$i.".jpg";
for ($i = 2; $i < 11; $i++) { 
    $file_path = "../uploads/properties/".$id."_".$i.".jpg";
    return $file_path;
}
if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    echo "file remove requested";
}else{
    echo "no file was requested to be removed";
}
?>
```

I know that the for loop is not going to work but basically I need the script to look at the `$id."_".$i`
and then if the file exists on the link that was clicked the file must get removed.

At the moment the solution that is working for me, is if I make 10 delete.php scripts and run this block of code in each one, the only part I would change in the script to get it to work is `$img` by setting it each time to `$img = "../../uploads/properties/".$id.".jpg";` next delete.php the value of `$img` will be `$img = "../../uploads/properties/".$id."_2.jpg";` etc.

So inside the **delete.php** at the moment the code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $current_page = 'properties_page.php';
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $clean_this = "delete_script/deletepic.php";
    $url = str_replace($clean_this, "properties_page.php", $url);
    $img = "../../uploads/properties/".$id.".jpg";
    unlink($img);
    header("Location:$url");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for my problem, so basically removing the loop and adding the extension of (_2.jpg) to the deletepic2.php `<a>` tag link like this:

**HTML**

*Code before fix was applied:*

```
<a target="_blank" href="delete_script/deletepic2.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>">Delete image</a>
```

*Code after fix was applied:*

```
<a target="_blank" href="delete_script/deletepic2.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($query, 0, "id"); ?>_2.jpg">Delete image</a>
```

And on the **deletepic2.php** file the code will execute to as follows:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $cleanLink = "delete_img.php";
    $url = str_replace($cleanLink, "properties_page.php", $url);
    $img = "../uploads/properties/".$id;
    unlink($img);
    header("Location:$url");
?>
```

So in essence no matter how many files I have in my directory by adding the unique string value of _(any number can go here).jpg to the  link in the html file I'm able to run the php script and target a specific file that I want the user to delete when the user clicks on the link of a specific file to be removed.

@rjdown thanks for the help I appreciate it. (two thumbs up)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code sample has some issues, for example SQL injection. Be aware that mysql_* functions are deprecated; you should look at using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. But that's not the question here so... your delete.php script should look something like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
$imageFolder = realpath('../../uploads/properties');

$imagePath = $imageFolder . '/' . $id . '.jpg';

if (file_exists($imagePath) && dirname(realpath($imagePath)) == $imageFolder) {
    unlink($imagePath);
    echo "file remove requested";
} else {
    echo "no file was requested to be removed";
}
```

Comment: check the `$imageFolder` is correct. In your example, it's `../../uploads/properties/`

Comment: LMAO it works but the bizzar thing is that it removes everything in the folder, dam looks like its back to the drawing board for me

Comment: Well, given an ID of say... 352... it will delete 352.jpg, 352_2.jpg, 352_3.jpg etc... but that's it. I tested the code, seems ok!

Comment: I see what you mean but is there not a way to look if the value was set from link tag that gets clicked to trigger the delete.php script?

Comment: but only if that specific image was selected to be deleted

Comment: I thought you wanted it to delete 352.jpg, 352_2.jpg, 352_3.jpg? Bit lost what you mean now. If you click on delete.php?id=352 then that's what it will do. Do you want to be able to delete say... ONLY 352_4.jpg? And not the whole set of 352s?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i need to happen, only the link that gets clicked, on that link i need the file to be removed, so in essence if the link on 352_4.jpg was requested to be deleted then it must only remove that image and leave the others

Comment: Ahh ok... I'll update the code in a bit, just doing dinner xD

Comment: Try that, it's a lot simpler. The realpath stuff is just extra security so they can't delete anything else other than images in your folder

Comment: So your links will need to be like... `delete.php?id=352` or `delete.php?id-352_7`